# How to shard only specific tables using vitess

Tags: mysql, distributed-database, vitess

I have created an unsharded keyspace with three tables. Now I would like to shard my keyspace for first two tables but don't want to shard the third table.

How can this be done? Vitess documentation does not contain any info or example regarding this. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vertical sharding in vitess is similar to horizontal sharding. You should use the vtworker VerticalSplitClone command instead of SplitClone.

We plan to fix the documentation to explain this, hopefully soon.

Comment: Ok Sugu. I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Tried with : "./sharded-vtworker.sh VerticalSplitClone --tables=test2 vtask/0" but it gives error like " vtworker.go:98] init() failed: destination keyspace vtask has no KeyspaceServedFrom". How to fix that?

Comment: How to implement this: http://vitess.io/overview/concepts/#served-from   ?