# Can we shard specific tables without creating new keyspace in vitess?

Tags: vitess

For Example: I want to create 40 tables in one keyspace. In 40 tables I want to shard 3 tables. Is is it possible to shard specific tables without creating new keyspace.
I have seen [How to shard only specific tables using vitess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022988/how-to-shard-only-specific-tables-using-vitess/59783933#59783933)  But for this we need to create new keyspace. I don't want to create new keyspace. I want sharded and unsharded tables in one keyspace is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. A keyspace is categorized as sharded or unsharded. So, you have to migrate the tables you want to shard into a sharded keyspace and then reshard the keyspace.

Some people worked around this by assigning a "null primary vindex" to the unsharded tables, essentially forcing all rows to live in the first shard. But I don't know if this was experimental or was actually used in production.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question.